# Parsing RSS/XML in php with namespaces

Tags: php, xml, parsing, rss

I have some RSS that looks like this:

```
<item>
<guid isPermaLink="false">2284767032</guid>
<title>title goes here...</title>
<description> Description </description>
<author>author name</author>
<dcterms:valid>start=2012-09-28T17:06:00Z;scheme=W3C-DTF</dcterms:valid>
<media:category scheme="" label="">cat1</media:category>
<media:category scheme="" label="">cat2</media:category>
<media:category scheme="" label="">cat3</media:category>

<media:copyright>Big Company</media:copyright>
<media:keywords>some;keywords;</media:keywords>
<media:group>
<media:content bitrate="643.386" medium="video" duration="72.144" expression="full" fileSize="5802051" framerate="29.97" type="video/x-flv" height="360" url="..." width="640"/>
<media:content bitrate="1242.571" medium="video" duration="72.144" expression="full" fileSize="11205501" framerate="29.97" type="video/x-flv" height="480" url="..." width="854"/>
</media:group>
<link>a234dfasf4f</link>
<plmedia:defaultThumbnailUrl>
  http://url.jpg
</plmedia:defaultThumbnailUrl>
</item>
```

I'm using the following code to parse it:

```
  $feed = simplexml_load_file('http://feedurl.com');
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($feed);
  echo "</pre>";
```

The problem is that I'm getting all the tags like **guid, title, and description**, but none of the `media:category` or `media:group` or `something:anything` show up - they are just stripped out.

How can I parse this feed without losing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find where the namespaces are defined, and find the string that the namespaces map to. So for example if the `media` namespace maps to `http://example.com/something`:

```
echo (string)$feed->children('http://example.com/something')->copyright;
```

Outputs:

> Big Company

The result of `print_r()` with SimpleXML does not always give you the full structure, but the elements are there.

To get the nested elements, try something like:

```
foreach($feed->children('http://example.com/something')->group->children('http://example.com/something')->content as $content)
{
    echo (string)$content->attributes()->bitrate;
}
```

Comment: Would that be in the header of the RSS document?

Comment: @Wes yes it usually is, for example: `<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">` this is the definition of the `itunes` namespace, defined as `http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd`.

Comment: Okay, is there anyway to combine them all into on big object/array?

Comment: This is working but for the nested ones I get this: http://wes.io/MFAk - how do I get that information?

Comment: You could manually add the data to a big array, other than that I don't think so. To get the nested ones I think you'd have to call `children()` again. See my edit.

Comment: @Wes no problem, +1 for the question